# Is there a performance advantage to multiple data.table assignments in one statement?

Tags: r, performance, data.table, variable-assignment

In `data.table`, the following have equivalent results:

```
dt1 <- data.table(iris)
dt1[, Long.Petal := Petal.Length > mean(Petal.Length)]
dt1[, Wide.Petal := Petal.Width > mean(Petal.Width)]
```

and

```
dt2 <- data.table(iris)
dt2[, `:=`(
  Long.Petal = Petal.Length > mean(Petal.Length),
  Wide.Petal = Petal.Width > mean(Petal.Width)
)]
```

When working with a *large* data set, is there a performance advantage (in terms of memory or running time or both) to the latter form? Or is the overhead minimal, and it's just a matter of style and readability?

Comment: the third form can be using chaning `dt3[, Long.Petal := ...][, Wide.Petal := ...]` but this probably will result the same overhead as `dt1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Things to take into account are a) the call to `[.data.table`, and b) running the code in `[.data.table`.

For a couple of calls, it shouldn't really affect. But if you're doing this 100's or 1000's of times (e.g., using a for-loop), then it could be less performant.. mostly due to the time for dispatching `[.data.table`. In that case, as long as there's no grouping, `set()` is a much better option.

In any case, these things are quite easy to benchmark for yourself on your dataset. Calling `Rprof(); <your_code>; Rprof(NULL); summaryRprof()` should give an idea of the time taken and where most of it is being spent.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about `set`, I never really used it before.

Comment: @Arun I find the benchmark in my answer pretty surprising. I would have expected the timings to be dominated by the time spent in `<` and `>` and thus didn't expect any difference.

Answer (score 4):

I'm surprised that there is actually a non-negligible performance difference in the following example. And it's not in favour of the combined assignment:

```
set.seed(42)
dt1 <- data.table(x = rnorm(1e7))
dt2 <- copy(dt1)

library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark({dt1[, y := x < 0]; dt1[, z := x > 0]},
               dt2[,`:=`(
                 y = x < 0,
                 z = x > 0
               )])
#Unit: milliseconds
#                                                   expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
#{     dt1[, `:=`(y, x < 0)]     dt1[, `:=`(z, x > 0)] } 122.6285 124.0237 143.3914 125.2057 146.0050 305.3609   100  a 
#                      dt2[, `:=`(y = x < 0, z = x > 0)] 153.2545 156.5720 208.5669 178.9714 301.8305 359.2821   100   b

all.equal(dt1, dt2)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: ha, I think it's because of reference counting. In the first case the expression evaluates to an atomic vector (with NAM(1)), i.e., there's no copy of RHS made in each assignment.. In the 2nd one, since it's a list, it needs to be copied (due to R's limitations in reference counting) I suppose... Nice catch! Perhaps we can optimise for some cases internally.. Should definitely file a FR.

Comment: @Roland, you can add chaining